# Get HashMap<Model1, List<Model2>> in an MVVM+Repostiory+LiveData setting?

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, repository-pattern, android-livedata, android-mvvm

So I was working on this silly little app for practicing MVVM and Repository Pattern. I have two model classes at the moment. They are `Category` and `SubCategory` for which I have defined the following data classes:

```
@Entity(tableName = "categories")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
) {
}
```

And

```
/**
 * One to many Relationship from Category to SubCategory
 */
@Entity(
    tableName = "sub_categories", foreignKeys = arrayOf(
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Category::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("category_id")
        )
    )
)
data class SubCategory(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_id")
    val categoryId: Int
) {
}
```

As you can see, I have modeled the resources such that we will need categoryId to be passed to get SubCategories related to a Category.

Now I am pretty new with this MVVM and LiveData and Repository Pattern.

My Problem is that I am using an `ExpandableListView` to populate SubCategories under Categories and the `Adapter` for it requires a `HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>` for it to display the expandable listview.

So my question is how do I get a `HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>` from my database using an approach of `db->dao->repository->viewmodel` and wherever the `adpater` goes.

I suppose creating a separate repository like `CategorySubCategoryRespository` whereby I can do something like following is not going to help?:

```
class CategorySubCategoryRepository(
        private val categoryDao: CategoryDao,
        private val subCategoryDao: SubCategoryDao
    ) {
    val allCategoriesSubCategories: LiveData<HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>>
        get() {
            val hashMap: HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>> = hashMapOf()
            for (category in categoryDao.getList()) {
                hashMap[category] = subCategoryDao.getSubCategoriesListForCategory(category.id)
            }
            return hashMap
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I think I want to use `LiveData` wherever possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was, in my `CategorySubcategoryRepository` I constructed the Hashmap from the `CategoryDao` and `SubcategoryDao` as follows:

```
class CategorySubCategoryRepository(
    private val categoryDao: CategoryDao,
    private val subCategoryDao: SubCategoryDao
) {

    fun getHashMap(): LiveData<HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>>()
        val hashMap: HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>> = hashMapOf()
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
            for (category in categoryDao.getList()) {
                hashMap[category] = subCategoryDao.getSubCategoriesListForCategory(category.id)
            }
        }
        data.value = hashMap
        return data
    }

}
```

Then I used this in my viewmodel's `init{}` block like:

```
hashMap = categorySubCategoryRepository.getHashMap()
```

Then I observed it in my Fragment's `onCreateView` as:

```
        myViewModel.hashMap.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.setCategoryList(it.keys.toList())
            adapter.setCategorySubCategoriesMap(it)
            elv_categories.setAdapter(adapter) 

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

Do Comment if this is not the right thing to do. I am doing this only to increase my skills and would love to hear if there's a better way to go about things or if my approach is completely absurd.

**Edit:**

As per @SanlokLee's comment. The `getHashMap` function has been changed to:

```
fun getHashMap(): LiveData<HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>>>()
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
            val hashMap: HashMap<Category, List<SubCategory>> = hashMapOf()
            for (category in categoryDao.getList()) {
                hashMap[category] = subCategoryDao.getSubCategoriesListForCategory(category.id)
            }
            data.postValue(hashMap)
        }
        return data
    }
```

Comment: 2 mistakes: modifying the same object that was already emitted, and not emitting anything after the data changes. You should create a new `HashMap` instance inside the `.execute` block. Then, you push that new hashmap to the `LiveData` using `data.postValue()` once all subcategories are collected.

Comment: Hey @SanlokLee. Thank you for your comment. I did what you suggested and I got the expected results on my UI too. Before doing what you suggested I was getting only three `Categories` on the UI despite having seven in the actual database. Thank you very much.